# Using ANTLR4 to flatten a hierarchy (like LESS to CSS)?

Tags: css, antlr4

LESS supports nested rulesets:

```
a {
  test: 1;
  #b {
    lol: 2;
  }
 }
```

The above code becomes:

```
a {test: 1;}
a#b {lol: 2;}
```

Can you do something similar with ANTLR4?

Comment: ANTLR is the parser generator, so you can use it to generate a parser for the input file. What you do about the parse result is up to you.

Comment: That's exactly my question. In all the visit methods I don't know the parent of a certain context. How would I parse and compile such a thing?

Comment: Your visitor should maintain a context stack. There are lots of docs about the visitor pattern, I'm pretty sure you can find a lot of info about this.